# UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed returns Theme4t in in mobile and no useful theme information

Tags: lightning, mobile, salesforce-classic, userinfo

I know that I can use UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() to get the current theme displayed to the user. This works in lightning and classic. However when I am in mobile mode, I just get "Theme4t" (as stated in the documentation.)

> Theme4t— Salesforce mobile app theme.

This doesn't give me any information about the type of theme displayed to the current user. How can I get the theme even if I am in mobile mode? (either classic or lightning theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what's returned for mobile, [a known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jl1UQAQ). According to the [SF documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm), to check between the Classic and LEX UI, verify if the "sforce.one" JavaScript object is available. This object would not be available in the Classic UI. If you want to render content specifically for mobile try something like this...

```
<apex:variable var="uiTheme" value="SalesforceApp" 
    rendered="{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4t'}">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AppStyles, 
                                     'mobile-styling.css')}" />
```

Related Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages

Comment: My question was to differentiate between lex and classic. anyway I tested using your method and this seems to work. Results:
classic only = false 
classic+mobile = false
lex = true
lex+mobile=true